# how to get types of input-type checkbox and radio in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

```
jQuery('.pricefield select','.pricefield input').each
    (jQuery(this).change (function (){
        alert(jQuery(this).attr("type")); //it give undefined
        alert(jQuery(this).is(':input')); //it gives false
        var allInputs = jQuery(":input"); 
        alert(allInputs.attr('type'));  //it gives hidden
        get_sum();
    }
));
```

How can I can identify the field type as `select` or `radio` or `checkbox`?

Comment: That syntax doesn't look right, `.each` expects a callback but you're passing a jQuery collection. Can you post a demo to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery('select, input', '.pricefield').on('change', function () {
     var tag  = $(this).prop('tagName'); // return "select", "input" etc
     var type = $(this).prop('type'); // return "radio", "checkbox" etc
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2m3xR/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You had some wrong syntax, missing a function declaration inside the `each()`, but actually you can write it more simple, like:

```
jQuery('.pricefield select, .pricefield input').change(function () {
    alert(jQuery(this).attr("type"));
    alert(jQuery(this).is(':input')); 
    var allInputs = jQuery(":input");
    alert(allInputs.attr('type'));
    get_sum();
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24vaF/2/)